# Fail to require image when using React 17 version

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am new to React and now learning the latest version with create-react-app. I met one issue hope someone could help.

```js
export default class LeftNav extends React.Component {
   show() {
     let test = '../../assets/images/test.png';
     let src = require('../../assets/images/test.png'); // test.png can be successfully loaded.
  
  // below 2 lines both throw compilation error saying it could not resolve test.png, but why 
  // directly require works
  // let src = require(test);
  // let src = require(`${test}`);
      return (
      <div className="container">
        <img src={src.default} alt=""/>
      </div>
      )
   }
   render() {
      return <div>{this.show()}</div>
   }
}
```

I have many images so it is not reasonable to import them one by one in the jsx file so that's why i am testing to dynamically include those assets. But the result shows we are not able to use variable to store asset path inside require(variable). Does someone know why this happens? is this a React bug? The react version i use is 17.0.1.  BTW, require() now returns an object so i use .src to get the real asset. thank you

Comment: what is src.default Any Logic Behind that ?

Comment: try removing the .default in the src

Comment: @AkshayRathodAr It is required in React 17 version, since now the require returns an object, I got this information when i searched on stack overflow.

Comment: @AppCity Thank you, but src.default is required in React 17 version, you can have a try, the issue is if we need to dynamically require an image inside a React component, it is not correct to use variable..

Comment: can you not use dynamic imports `import(..)`?